# Oracle 10g cannot see any data in tables

Tags: oracle, redhat

Im getting this error in Oracle 10g log file

```
2010-11-12 16:07:41.838: [  OCROSD][3069777600]utgdv:2:ocr loc file  cannot  be opened
2010-11-12 16:07:41.865: [  OCROSD][3069777600]utopen:1: Couldnt find ocr,[ocrmirror] location in config file
2010-11-12 16:07:41.865: [  OCRRAW][3069777600]proprinit: Could not open raw device 
2010-11-12 16:07:41.865: [ default][3069777600]a_init:7!: Backend init unsuccessful : [33]
2010-11-12 16:07:41.865: [ CSSCLNT][3069777600]clsssinit: error(33 ) in OCR initialization
```

I was able to connect but can't generate table data form my client program. Plus it was working earlier. Im running on Redhat EL 5

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect Oracle cluster configuration.
Instance can't open Oracle Cluster Registry volume.

Perhaps it's rights issue or bug 9236255.

If you've not RAC environment then Ignore the message.

I think you've problem with datafiles storage.